# Crash when re-using std::function loaded from pybind

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to define an accumulator in python, which C++ code is free to fill whenever it sees fit.

To achieve this, I am building an accumulator on the python side, giving it to the C++ code so that it can use it whenever, and then calling the C++ code from the python side, as follows:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/functional.h>

class Wrapper {
  public : 
    Wrapper() {}

    void store_accu_function(std::function<void(const std::string&)> &accu_function) {
    // stores accu_function
    }

    void call_accu_function(std::string x) {
    // calls the stored accu_function on x
    }

};

PYBIND11_MODULE(PythonModule, module_handle) {
    py::class_<Wrapper>(module_handle, "LocationFusionWrapper")
      .def(py::init<>())
      .def("store_accu_function", &Wrapper::store_accu_function)
      .def("call_accu_function", &Wrapper::call_accu_function)
```

```py
class Accu :

  def __init__():
    self.output = []

  def add_new_output(s : str):
    self.output.append(s)
    
import CModule
c_wrapper = CModule.Wrapper()
accumulator = Accu()
c_wrapper.store_accu_function(accumulator.add_new_output)
c_wrapper.call_accu_function("x") # crash
```

If I try to call `accumulator.add_new_output` from within `store_accu_function` then everything works fine. However subsequent calls using `call_accu_function` seem to always result in a crash. What is going on? Is there a way to make this work ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of your problem, but `add_new_output` is a method of the class `Accu`, so it expects the first argument to be `self` *(it is missing in the method declaration)*. Passing `"x"` as the only argument would give you an error in pure Python as well. So make sure your Python code works standalone before trying to mix with your C++ code.

Comment: It's possible `accumulator` is being garbage collected before `call_accu_function` is reached. You can check by adding `print(accumulator)` or something afterwards to keep it in scope. If this is the problem, then [this page](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/functions.html) will be helpful..

Comment: also, it's easier for people to check things if you provide a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).